# Caching Django query results for __unicode__ calls that refer to related objects

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following models:

```
class Territory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    power = models.ForeignKey(Power, null=True, blank=True)
    is_supply = models.BooleanField()

class Subregion(models.Model):
    territory = models.ForeignKey(Territory)
    subname = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    sr_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SUBREGION_CHOICES)
    init_unit = models.BooleanField()
    borders = models.ManyToManyField("self", null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.subname:
            return u'%s (%s)' % (self.territory.name, self.subname)
        else:
            return u'%s [%s]' % (self.territory.name, self.sr_type)
```

The problem is that when rendering a `ModelFormSet`, each form of which has 3 `ModelChoiceFields` containing all 120 `Subregions`, an individual `SELECT` query is generated for each `Subregion` in each widget.  According to my Postgres logs, over 1000 queries are being generated for a simple 3-form formset, with a noticeable effect on page load times.

So, is there a reasonable way to do a single large query that will cache all of the information that `Subregion.__unicode__()` wants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [select_related()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4)?  This will help you with the extra look ups for territory.name.  The borders will be skipped because select_related()'s default is to not follow foreign keys where null=True.  You can try being explicit with the names of the related objects if you need to get the borders as well: `Subregion.objects.select_related('territory', 'borders').all()`.

Take this for a spin in your app's `./manage.py shell` and see if select_related() helps:

```
>>> from django import db
>>> db.reset_queries()
>>> Subregion.objects.all()
# ...
>>> len(db.connection.queries)
# some big number
>>> db.reset_queries()
>>> Subregion.objects.select_related().all()
# ...
>>> len(db.connection.queries)
# a smaller number
```

Comment: I had previously tried using `select_related` by constructing a queryset with it, then passing that queryset to all of the `ModelChoiceFields` using a `formfield_callback`.  No difference in number of queries.  However, your code above did have an effect (21 vs 1).

Comment: ...And this would be because I made a mistake in my callback function.  Yes, `select_related` is sufficient, taking it from 1136 select queries to only 56.  Much better, thanks.

Comment: Or use a custom Manager with `select_related()` as mentioned [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262036/django-unicode-and-fk-is-very-slow) and similar to what is in [documentation of Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).